# Replace 3 lines with another line SED Syntax

Tags: sed

This is a simple question, I'm not sure if i'm able to do this with sed/awk
How can I make sed search for these 3 lines and replace with a line with a determined string?

```
<Blarg>
<Bllarg>
<Blllarg>
```

replace with

```
<test>
```

I tried with sed `"s/<Blarg>\n<Bllarg>\n<Blllarg>/<test>/g"` But it just don't seem to find these lines. Probably something with my break line character (?) `\n`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because sed usually handles only one line at a time, your pattern will never match. Try this:

```
sed '1N;$!N;s/<Blarg>\n<Bllarg>\n<Blllarg>/<test>/;P;D' filename
```

Comment: sorry, it works indeed. Instead of using <Blarg>, using <\/Blarg>, make it dont work. (The infile was changed too)

Comment: @ghaschel, if it doesn't work in your real file, give us more information and maybe we can help.

Comment: It search, find the the text block, replace with <test> and don't replace another occurrence in the file.

Comment: @ghaschel to replace all such blocks in a file, use: `sed ':a;/\n/!{$!N};$!N;s/<Blarg>\n<Bllarg>\n<Blllarg>$/<test>/;ta;P;D'`

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/<Blarg>/ {N;N;s/<Blarg>\n<Bllarg>\n<Blllarg>/<test>/}' <filename>
```

It works as follows:

- Search the file till `<Blarg>` is found
- Then append the two following lines to the current pattern space using `N;N;`
- Check if the current pattern space matches `<Blarg>\n<Bllarg>\n<Blllarg>`
- If so, then substitute it with `<test>`

Comment: It works like a charm. in a test file, but when i try in the file i need, it just won't work...

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the content of the actual file?

Comment: This won't work for ` echo -e '<Blarg>\n<Blarg>\n<Bllarg>\n<Blllarg>'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [range addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses) with regular expressions an the [c](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-c-_0028change-to-text-lines_0029-command) command, which does exactly what you are asking for:

```
sed '/<Blarg>/,/<Blllarg>/c<test>' filename
```